# Hazelcast with global serializer (Kryo) - There is no suitable de-serializer for type

Tags: java, deserialization, hazelcast, kryo

I’m using Hazelcast 3.9 to cluster user sessions.

To serialize the session objects, I created a global serializer implemented with Kryo (or more precisely KryoReflectionFactorySupport that allow to serialize objects without default constructor).

```
public class GlobalKryoSerializer implements StreamSerializer<Object> {
    //use ThreadLocal because Kryo is not thread safe
    private static final InheritableThreadLocal <Kryo> kryoThreadLocal = new InheritableThreadLocal <Kryo>() {
        @Override
        protected Kryo initialValue() {
           Kryo kryo = new KryoReflectionFactorySupport();
           //Kryo uses its own class loader       
           kryo.setClassLoader(java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
           return kryo;
        }
    };

    public GlobalKryoSerializer(){    }

    public int getTypeId() {
        return 123;
    }

    public void destroy() {    }

    public void write(ObjectDataOutput objectDataOutput, Object object) throws IOException {
        Output output = new Output((OutputStream) objectDataOutput);
        Kryo kryo = kryoThreadLocal.get();
        kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, object);
        output.flush();
    }

    public Object read(ObjectDataInput objectDataInput) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = (InputStream) objectDataInput;
        Input input = new Input(in);
        Kryo kryo = kryoThreadLocal.get();
        Object retVal = kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Hazelcast.xml is similar to https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/resources/hazelcast-default.xml with global serializer configuration:

```
<serialization>
      <portable-version>0</portable-version>
      <serializers>
           <global-serializer override-java-serialization="true"> GlobalKryoSerializer</global-serializer>       
      </serializers>
</serialization>
```

When the session is invalidated, Hazelcast fails to de-serialize with the error below (the “type number” varies from time to time):

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable de-serializer for type 16843028. This exception is likely to be caused by differences in the serialization configuration betw
een members or between clients and members.
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.newHazelcastSerializationException(AbstractSerializationService.java:236) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:263) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:570) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSession.deserializeMap(HazelcastSession.java:141) ~[hazelcast-tomcat7-sessionmanager-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSession.readData(HazelcastSession.java:127) ~[hazelcast-tomcat7-sessionmanager-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:158) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:105) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:50) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:185) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.toObject(MapProxySupport.java:1149) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.remove(MapProxyImpl.java:212) ~[hazelcast-all-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSessionManager.remove(HazelcastSessionManager.java:328) ~[hazelcast-tomcat7-sessionmanager-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at com.hazelcast.session.HazelcastSessionManager.remove(HazelcastSessionManager.java:294) ~[hazelcast-tomcat7-sessionmanager-1.1.2.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:833) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.82]
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:732) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.82]
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.invalidate(StandardSession.java:1264) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.82]
        at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.invalidate(StandardSessionFacade.java:183) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.82]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler.logout(SecurityContextLogoutHandler.java:65) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Can you please check if all the Hazelcast cluster members have access to/use the same configuration?

Comment: I'm currently checking the exception only with one app server

Comment: I think my question is misunderstood. Do the all Hazelcast members have the same configuration?

Comment: There is only on member that reads the configuration from the hazelcast.xml I described above. This is the log from hazelcast:

Comment: [com.hazelcast.config.UrlXmlConfig] <Configuring Hazelcast from 'file:/conf/hazelcast.xml'.>
...
[com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService] <[172.16.200.65]:5701 [qaapp] [3.9] [172.16.200.65]:5701 is STARTING>
...
Members {size:1, ver:1} [
 Member [172.16.200.65]:5701 - fcf18ad9-0a8c-4adf-8715-bf659782fc9a this
]
...
[com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService] <[172.16.200.65]:5701 [qaapp] [3.9] [172.16.200.65]:5701 is STARTED>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast's Tomcat Based Web Session Replication only supports `Serializable` objects as Session objects when you need to cluster them. This requirement also applies when a global serializer is set up in the cluster configuration. Thus, you need to make your session objects `Serializable` to make it work.

You can also find this requirement in the documentation: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager#features-and-requirements

I've raised a Github issue on the repo regarding this request, please track the process from there: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

Adding Kryo to the global serializer didn't work for me. I had to add it as a regular serializer. Spring boot example:

```
Config config = new Config();
/* other hazelcast configs omittedfor brevity */
SerializerConfig kyroSerizlier = new SerializerConfig()
                .setImplementation(new GlobalKryoSerializer())
                .setTypeClass(Object.class);
config.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(kyroSerizlier);
```