# How to correctly configure a global serializer?

Tags: serialization, configuration, hazelcast, payara

I'm trying to configure a global serializer for Hazelcast 3.12 (My application runs on payara 5 which comes bundled with this version of Hazelcast so I cannot update to 4.x)

According to the manual (https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/manual/html-single/index.html#global-serializer) implementing and configuring a global serializer should be simple, here is my Serializer:

```
public class MyGlobalStreamSerializer implements StreamSerializer<Object> {
    private static FSTConfiguration conf = FSTConfiguration.createDefaultConfiguration();

    @Override
    public int getTypeId() {
        return 123;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(ObjectDataOutput objectDataOutput, Object o) throws IOException {
        objectDataOutput.write(conf.asByteArray(o));
    }

    @Override
    public Object read(ObjectDataInput objectDataInput) throws IOException {
        return conf.asObject(objectDataInput.readByteArray());
    }
}
```

I'm using fast-serialization for the actual serialization implementation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.ruedigermoeller</groupId>
    <artifactId>fst</artifactId>
    <version>2.57</version>
</dependency>
```

And the serialization configuration in my hazelcast-config.xml

```
<serialization>
    <portable-version>0</portable-version>
    <serializers>            
        <global-serializer override-java-serialization="true" >de.mycompany.myapp.domain.MyGlobalStreamSerializer</global-serializer>
    </serializers>
</serialization>
```

however at application startup I get a NullPointerException when the configuration is built:

```
[2020-10-20T12:37:14.348+0200] [Payara 5.2020] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00014] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1603190234348] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Shutdown required
MultiException stack 1 of 1
MultiException stack 1 of 4
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore.buildConfiguration(HazelcastCore.java:333)
        at fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore.bootstrapHazelcast(HazelcastCore.java:480)
        at fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore.getInstance(HazelcastCore.java:234)
        at fish.payara.nucleus.config.ClusteredConfig.postConstruct(ClusteredConfig.java:99)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:679)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:54)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:188)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:211)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:334)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:821)
MultiException stack 2 of 4
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.nucleus.config.ClusteredConfig
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:679)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:54)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:188)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:211)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:334)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:821)
MultiException stack 3 of 4
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of fish.payara.nucleus.requesttracing.RequestTracingService errors were found
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:224)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:334)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:821)
MultiException stack 4 of 4
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on fish.payara.nucleus.requesttracing.RequestTracingService
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:363)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:821)
]]
```

Omitting the package / using just the class name as value for global-serializer in the configuration as seen in the manual didn't work either, my last attempt was with the full path because that's how it's done in the hazelcast-full-example.xml that comes with the release.

I also saw another post here where someone was trying to implement a global serializer using Kryo as implementation for the actual serialization, the code and config looked pretty much the same but he didn't seem to have my problem ([Hazelcast with global serializer (Kryo) - There is no suitable de-serializer for type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428131/hazelcast-with-global-serializer-kryo-there-is-no-suitable-de-serializer-for))
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Payara Server uses its own serializer which can't be disabled, see the docs: https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2020.5/documentation/payara-server/hazelcast/configuration.html. The Payara serializer delegates to a Hazelcast global serializer which is specified in the Hazelcast config. This serialized should be in the Payara Server's classpath, it's not enough to add it to your application.

Try adding a JAR file with `MyGlobalStreamSerializer` and all its dependencies (e.g. the `fst` JAR and its dependencies) to the `lib` directory in your domain directory, this will add it to the server's classpath. Here's the docs on the `asadmin add-library` command, which you can use: https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2020.5/documentation/payara-server/asadmin-commands/misc-commands.html#add-library-command.

In your case, it seems that the exception is thrown when Payara Server wants to log a message that your global serializer is not a subclass of StreamSesrializer which the Payara serializer expects: https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/nucleus/payara-modules/hazelcast-bootstrap/src/main/java/fish/payara/nucleus/hazelcast/HazelcastCore.java#L333

That code hasn't changed in any version of Payara Server 5.2020.x and the only way it can throw a NullPointerException is if the global serializer is `null`. I expect this happens because Hazelcast can't find the class of your serializer and returns null for the serializer.